# Access host machine in Docker Container on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker

I am looking for a way to connect to my host machine in a Docker Container (in my case, access to a specific port for using a proxy in the application container).

I tried `network_mode: "host"` (or `docker run --network="host"`), it worked in case of accessing to local machine but caused some other problems which were related to changing network driver to `host`:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.

Also I can not use `ifconfig` to define network alias since I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: @DavidMaze No, it's not. I don't want to change my network driver because of the weird problems which it made.

Comment: Your question seems literally the same as that question.  I tend to think `--net host` is usually a hack, but the second and third answers to that question give some useful alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Since the `docker-host` (https://github.com/qoomon/docker-host) image is published in the last few months, you can use that without any manual configuration. Easy peasy!

After struggling for a day, finally found the solution. It can be done by ***--add-host*** flag in `docker run` command or ***extra_hosts*** in a `docker-compose.yml` file with making an alias for Local (`lo | 127.0.0.1` ) network interface.

So here are the instructions:

1. First, create an alias for `lo` interface. As you may know, `ifconfig` command does not exist on Ubuntu 18.04 so this is how we do it:

`sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.20/24 dev lo label lo:1`

2. Then, put this on you ***docker-compose.yml*** file:

```
extra_hosts:
      - "otherhost:192.168.0.20"
```

If ***you are not*** using *Docker Compose* you can add a host to a container by `--add-host` flag. Something like 
`docker run container-name --add-host="otherhost:192.168.0.20"`

3. Finally, when you're done with the above steps, restart your containers with `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` or `docker-compose restart`

Now you can log-in to your container (`docker-compose exec container-name bash`) and test it.

**NOTE**: Make sure your working port is open using `telnet [interface-ip] [port]` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `extra_hosts` in you docker-compose, which is what you discovered by yourself. I just wanted to add another way when you are working on your local environment.

In **docker-for-mac** and **docker-for-windows**, within a container the DNS name `host.docker.internal` resolves to an IP address allowing network access to the host.

Here's the related description, extracted from [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds):

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker for Windows.

There's an [open issue on github](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264) concerning the implementation of this feature for **docker-for-linux**.